# PHP textarea combined with select change and .load() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a textarea where I will load the term respective to the value of my select. I'm loading the content to the textarea using .load("load_myinvoices_default_terms.php?id="+id). I can load the content successfully. But when I'm to type on the textarea and then change the selected option, the .load() function wont load anymore.

My hunch is that when I type on the textarea it is put on the value, while on I use the .load it is put on the html. 
I just want to be able to type on the textarea and still be able to change it's value when I change the selected option.

invoice.php:

```
<select id="setDefaultTermSelection" name="invoice_term_id" onChange="load_myinvoices_default_terms();">
    <option value="0">Set as new term</option>
    <option value="1">Term 1</option>
    <option value="2">Term 2</option>
</select>

<textarea id="default_terms" name="invoice_terms" placeholder="Enter your terms and conditions" rows="5"></textarea>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function load_myinvoices_default_terms()
{
    var id = $("#setDefaultTermSelection").val();
    $("#default_terms").load("load_myinvoices_default_terms.php?id="+id);
}

$("#default_terms").keyup(function(e)
{
    $("#setDefaultTermSelection").val(0);
});
</script>
```

load_myinvoices_default_terms.php:

```
<?php
    include ("includes/connection.php");

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    if($id > 0)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM terms WHERE user_id = $_SESSION[user_id] AND term_id = $id";
        $selectQuery = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery);

        echo $row['term_description'];
    }
    else
        echo "";
?>
```

Comment: I've also tried putting this inside load_myinvoices_defaul_terms():

$("#default_terms").val($("#default_terms").html())

but something is still off.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that, when you set your select value programmatically like this: `$("#setDefaultTermSelection").val(0);`, the event `change` is **not** triggered.

`onchange` only triggers when the user clicks. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change):

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`
>   elements when a change to the element's value **is committed by the
>   user**. Unlike the input event, the change event is **not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value**.

But, you can trigger the change manually (*"simulating"* user click) with the jQuery's [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method. Something like this:

```
$("#setDefaultTermSelection").val("0");
$("#setDefaultTermSelection").trigger("change");
```

Or (one line):

```
$("#setDefaultTermSelection").val("0").change();
```

In the last example, [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) is an alias for `.trigger("change")`

Some points:

1. The `value` inside `<option>` tag is a string. So, you should set the value with `.val("0");`.
2. The event according to [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) is actually `onchange`, and not `onChange` (capital "C"). However, modern browsers actually accept both ways.

Comment: still doesnt work sir. but thanks for the .trigger() :)

Comment: I was thinking is there some jquery code that could queue the scripts in order? like:

1. $("#default_terms").load("load_myinvoices_default_terms.php?id="+id);
2. alert($("#default_terms").val());

executes #2 only after #1 has been done?

Comment: `.load` accepts a complete callback as second argument: `.load(url, function() { /* code to run when load is complete */ });`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
First, I've put these on my script  as mrlew suggested.

```
$("#setDefaultTermSelection").val("0");
$("#setDefaultTermSelection").trigger("change");
```

then on the load_myinvoices_default_terms.php:

```
<?php
    include ("includes/connection.php");

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    if($id > 0)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM terms WHERE user_id = $_SESSION[user_id] AND term_id = $id";
        $selectQuery = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery);

        $x = $row['term_description'];
        json_encode($x);
    }
    else
        echo "";
?>
<script>
    var ar = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
    $("#default_terms").val(ar);
</script>
```

tho there are more efficient ways of solving this, so please let me know, thanks :)

Comment: oh on second thoughts its more ok not to have the .$("#setDefaultTermSelection").trigger("change");
because it will cause to lose focus on the textarea.